# How do expressions like "more than" and "is more than" have different meanings?

Tags: terminology, arithmetic

I've looked up in my present math book that expressions like (1) "less than" and "is less than" and (2) "more than" and "is more than" have different meanings.  I saw that "less than" indicates subtraction and "is less than" indicates a number that's smaller than another, likewise for "more than" and "is more than." Am I on the right track?  I told you before that I got this out of the math book I have right now.  Please help me on this!

Comment: Can you give full examples for these usages?

Comment: What is the book (title, authors, edition)?

Comment: Maybe the author has in mind sentences like "Wilma has 10 coconuts and Fred has 6 less than Wilma."  So Fred has 4 coconuts.  Though the grammar seems questionable.

Comment: I think OP means "5 less 3 is 2."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're correct

It's like $20$ is $5$ less than $15$ and

$20$ is less than $21$

Comment: I hope you're right about this one!

Comment: @Mathster same here.

Comment: So you're on the same page as me?  Well, I hope your works also gets up-voted!

Comment: @Mathster Well, You too can upvote, and I don't what are you studying exactly. I'm an Indian and I'm studying First Year Engineering.

Comment: Well, I _have_ earned the privilege, so why isn't it working?

Comment: @Mathster I've no Idea.

Comment: Well, "more than" indicates addition and "is more than" indicates that one number has a bigger value than the other one, likewise for "less than" and "is less than."